# ASUS RT-AC88U WAN Connectivity Issues Unsolved

Tags: router, internet-connection, asuswrt-merlin, asuswrt

I've been running Asuswrt-Merlin on an ASUS RT-AC88U for the last 2 years with a rented comcast modem in bridge mode. Late last fall I began encountering intermittent internet connectivity issues where my connection dies for 20-60 seconds. The issue can occur in rapid succession for hours and can disappear for hours. However, it seems to be escalating lately.

EDIT: This occurs for all clients connected wireless or wired. Connectivity within the network is unaffected.

I've tried various things to isolate and correct the issue:

- Bypassed the router and connected directly to the modem. Configured the modem back to router mode. The problem no longer occurs.
- Flashed firmware to most recent version
- Rolled back firmware to the version I used when I first bought the modem
- Flashed to most recent stock Asuswrt
- Executing `service "restart_wan_if 0"` through SSH to restart the WAN forces the router to recover much more quickly

In all cases I've done a complete factory reset and configured the router without any of the extra "bells and whistles" enabled (i.e. OpenVPN, DNSMasq, Adaptive QoS).

This is what I'm seeing:

```
2/6/2024 10:22:05 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=57
2/6/2024 10:22:09 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:14 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:19 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:24 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:29 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:34 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:39 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:44 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:49 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:22:50 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=57
.
.
2/6/2024 10:38:30 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57
2/6/2024 10:38:35 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:38:40 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:38:45 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:38:50 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:38:55 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:38:56 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=57
.
.
2/6/2024 10:53:31 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=57
2/6/2024 10:53:36 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:53:41 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:53:46 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:53:51 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:53:56 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:54:01 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:54:06 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 10:54:07 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
.
.
2/6/2024 11:06:22 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=57
2/6/2024 11:06:27 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 11:06:32 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 11:06:37 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 11:06:42 PM - Request timed out.
2/6/2024 11:06:43 PM - Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=57
```

While I'm fairly certain now that the issue is with the router and not the modem (I have yet to change out the modem to a newer model with Comcast which will be my next step), I am wondering if the issue is on Comcast's side. I do believe they performed "maintenance" in my area and the issue began after that.

Help me internet gods, you're my only hope!

Comment: Does this occur on all connected clients? Have you verified the ethernet cable between the modem and router is good by temporarily replacing with a known good cable? Please post the output of the system and kernel logs when the issue occurs, anonymizing the WAN IP and any DDNS address. It seems unlikely the Comcast modem+router combo is the issue since it doesn't occur when connected to it directly, bypassing the Asus router.

Comment: This occurs for all clients connected wireless or wired. Connectivity within the network is unaffected. Changing the cable has no effect. Though this is a good day for the router it seems and I've only had one brief drop. No logs at that time. I've increased the sensitivity of the log filter. Will update when I encounter another drop.